# SQL Oracle get the all columns of a cursor to use in a insert into

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to create a procedure in which I use a cursor to select certain lines and then insert them in another table. I wonder if there is a notation to write it faster. 
For instance here is the complete procedure

```
create or replace procedure myProc as
  Cursor lines is
    select * from table1 where c = '2';
   begin
      for line in lines loop
        insert into table2 values(line.a, line.b, line.c, line.d ....);
      end loop;
   end;
/
```

I want to know if I can replace the 'insert into' line by something like

```
insert into table2 values(line.something);
```

or

```
insert into tables2 values(something(line));
```

(I think a view could be more effective but it's not the question here.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely:

```
create or replace procedure myProc as
begin
  insert into table2( . . .)
    select a, b, c, d, . . 
    from table1
    where c = '2';
end;
/
```

You should list the columns in `table2` as well.  That is what the `table2( . . . )` means.

Comment: I didn't know this way... So there is nothing with the cursor ?

Why should I list the columns in `table2` ?

Comment: @Ccile . . . You should avoid cursors.  Period.  Sometimes they are necessary.  In that case, use them.  You should list the columns so you are sure that the right values are inserted into the right columns.

Comment: Why ?
Ok for the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the following code should work in case structure of both tables were identical...

```
INSERT INTO target_table
  SELECT * FROM source_table;
```

... you should avoid this way of programming because any column addition to source or target table will end in SQL became invalid.

Comment: The use of * was only to say that I select a lot of columns and I don't want to write line.name1, line.name2 etc.
I know I have to write it at least once (twice with the cursor) and my question was about how to use cursor and only write one time the names.

Comment: You can use a dynamic cursor and query ALL_TAB_COLUMNS in order to produce the column list for both INSERT and SELECT.

Comment: ALL_TAB_COLUMNS is for * ? If I want all columns except one ?

Comment: you simply add "WHERE COLUMN_NAME != column_I_dont_want

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're looking for a short-cut in order to avoid qualifying column names in an `insert` statement.

Well, although I do not recommend this, it can be done bug it's a little tedious. Here is an example:

1. if you have a table `employee (employee_id, employee_name, designation)`. You'll need to create two types in the database-

   a. An object type which is similar to `employee`-

   ```
       create type employee_obj as object  (employee_id   number(28,0),
                                            employee_name varchar2(100),
                                            designation   varchar2(30));
   ```

   b. Create the set type of this record-

   ```
       create type employee_obj_set is table of employee_obj;
   ```

   c. In your PL/SQL procedure you can use something like:

   ```
       DECLARE
           empset employee_obj_set;
           -- More variables here
       BEGIN
           -- other operations
           -- populate your empset
           -- other operations
           INSERT INTO employee
               SELECT * FROM table(empset);
           -- other operations
       END;
       /
   ```

Answer (score 0):

For faster inserts use bulk collect/FORALL insert instead of singular inserts.Find below sample...

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR lines is select * from table1 where c = '2';
    type lines_ty is table of table2%rowtype;
    l_lines_t2 lines_ty;
BEGIN
    OPEN lines;
    LOOP
    FETCH lines BULK COLLECT INTO l_lines_t2 LIMIT 500;
    FORALL i IN 1..l_lines_t2.COUNT
        INSERT INTO table2 VALUES l_lines_t2(i);
        EXIT WHEN lines%NOTFOUND;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE lines;
END;
```